# October CMS builder plugin

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I am running through the october cms tutorial video series and I am n the 5th video. After following all the steps using the builder plugin, I go to create a record and I get an error when it redirects to the update page, danc/jobs/jobs/update/1. I also am not seeing any records in my list page. After checking the database, those records are in there.

Any help would be awesome. I am still on the fence about this cms...

Comment: Can you include details of the error in the question?

Comment: The error says Form record with an ID of 1 could not be found.

I rebuilt the plugin and it works.  I was unable to debug it though which kind of irks me...

Comment: Ok, I am still running into this issue.  I have no idea why I am getting this.  I am following the tutorial except i am changing names for the project i am building.  This is kind of ridiculous.